# How to call method on spring proxy once initialised

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I read the following issue on jira:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-2740

Basically, I want my spring MVC application to load some data from a database on initialization.  As the init method / @Preconstruct is invoked before any AOP proxying is done there is no transaction advice applied.

Is there an elegant pattern to follow so once proxying has taken place I can configure something similar to the init method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the autowired resource for this single initialization point you can simply @Autowire a method with the resource needed.

```
@Autowired
public void initialized(Database database){
     resources =  resource.loadDatabaseRecources();
}
```

This will autowire the Database instance to this method after `Database` is finishing initializing.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is simple and elegant.

Extract loading data from the database into a separate transactional method in **different** class. Then inject that class and use it in `@PostConstruct`.

So instead of:

```
@Resource
private DataSource ds;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ds...
}
```

you get:

```
@Resource
private Dao dao;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    dao.readSomeStuff();
}
```

Where `Dao` has:

```
@Resource
private DataSource ds;

@Transactional
public Stuff readSomeStuff() {
    ds...
}
```

This introduces another level of indirection, but extracting DAOs insto separate classes might be a good idea, depending on your architecture.