# integration testing spring service layer based on migrated data

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, junit4

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Resource(name="myService")
    public MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testSeomthing() {
    //do some asserts using myService.whatever()
    }
}
```

However the tests are based on data I migrate in, so every time I run my suite of tests I want to execute my unrelated migration code.  I don't want to run a `@Before` in each test class. I want to run it once at beginning of complete test process, where can I put this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to create a test bean somewhere with startup logic invoked in `@PostConstruct`:

```
@Service
public class TestBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //startup logic here
    }

}
```

Obviously this bean should only be created for tests, the easiest way to achieve this is to place it in `src/test/java` in a package that is `component-scan`ned by Spring for `@Service`-annotated classes.

*Note:* you must remember that `@PostConstruct` is not running in a transaction! See [How to call method on spring proxy once initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082885).

Answer (score 1):

JUnit also offers a @BeforeClass annotation which you can place on a static method to initialize resources just once.

Comment: thankyou, but I don't understand entirely. I'd have a separate class that would have a static method, that I would annotate ? Or a static method in each test class ?

Comment: One static method in each test class. Not exactly sure if the @BeforeClass is inherited. (may want to check the docs on that)

Comment: so then it would be run for each test class ? I wanted it be run once for all tests ... ?

Comment: It would be run for each test class, yes. If you need to run a method once before all tests, you should create a TestCase and create the method in there. Added dependency is that you have to always run the tests through the TestCase.